# emacs minimal install for Ubuntu server use

Tags: install, ubuntu

Is there a minimal version of emacs?

When using `apt get install emacs24` on a 16.04 LTS machine the packet manager propose me to install 200 MB worth of stuff...

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  adwaita-icon-theme at-spi2-core colord colord-data dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service emacs emacs24 emacs24-bin-common
  emacs24-common emacs24-common-non-dfsg emacs24-el emacsen-common gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2-common
  glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services gsettings-desktop-schemas humanity-icon-theme imagemagick-common
  libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatspi2.0-0 libboost-filesystem1.58.0 libboost-system1.58.0 libcairo-gobject2 libcolord2 libcolorhug2
  libcroco3 libdconf1 libegl1-mesa libepoxy0 libfftw3-double3 libgbm1 libgconf-2-4 libgphoto2-6 libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port12
  libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgudev-1.0-0 libgusb2 libieee1284-3 libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common
  liblockfile-bin liblockfile1 liblqr-1-0 libm17n-0 libmagickcore-6.q16-2 libmagickwand-6.q16-2 libmirclient9 libmircommon5
  libmirprotobuf3 libotf0 libprotobuf-lite9v5 libproxy1v5 librest-0.7-0 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsane libsane-common
  libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1-mesa libwayland-server0 libxcb-xfixes0
  libxft2 libxkbcommon0 libxt6 m17n-db ubuntu-mono

Is there a way to get "just" the terminal based emacs?

I need to keep the footprint of the program as small as possible to avoid unnecessary maintenance to a streamlined server.

Comment: This sounds like you should not install emacs at all but use `tramp` to remotely connect and edit from your working machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably `emacs24-nox` is the package you want instead.